# how to remove white bar in the unity screen in ios?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, unity-game-engine

I am developing the unity game in iOS, Converting unity project into xcode project and integrating swift library to the generated xcode project.In my library having the some view controllers.

running game into the device it is showing the white bar in game screen as well as library screen also. [image: game screen]

[image: library screen]

First one is my game screen and second one is my library screen.In both screen it is showing the white color bar in the top.how to remove that bar?Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try to put this in `viewDidLoad` method:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
```

Comment: Move that code to viewWillAppear() instead of viewDidLoad().

viewDidLoad() is only called once per instantiated view controller, whereas viewWillAppear() is called whenever the view controller is about to be presented on screen.